# How to insert a generated a data inside a table in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to insert my generated data inside a table and a table row. As you can see it only has a border in it. I need it for it to look neat. Any idea how to do it?

Here's the code i've been playing:

HTML:

```
<input id="from" />
<input id="to" />
<button id="getBetween">Get Between Dates</button>
<div id=""></div>
<input type="text" id="count" />


<table border="1" >
    <tr id="results">
        <td></td>    
    </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
    (function() {
    Date.prototype.toYMD = Date_toYMD;
    function Date_toYMD() {
        var year, month, day;
        year = String(this.getFullYear());
        month = String(this.getMonth() + 1);
        if (month.length == 1) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        day = String(this.getDate());
        if (day.length == 1) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    }
})();

$("#from").datepicker();
$("#to").datepicker();


$('#getBetween').on('click', function () {
    var start = $("#from").datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $("#to").datepicker('getDate');
    var currentDate = new Date(start);
     var between = [];
   // alert(start);
   // alert(end);

    while (currentDate <= end) {
        var a = new Date(currentDate);
        var b = a.toYMD();
        between.push(b);
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);

    }

    $('#results').html(between.join('</br></table> '));
    $('#count').val(between.length);
});
```

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

A simple join will not work. Try:

```
var res = '';
between.forEach(function (s) {
    res += '<td>' + s + '</td>';
});
$('#results').html(res);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. Your code works. But what if i want the table to be vertical not horizontal? Here is my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/TMsXM/240/

Answer (score 0):

You can create elements HTML e after append on your table (#results)

See below:

```
var table = $('#results');

for (var i in between) {
    var line = $(document.createElement("tr")),
        column = $(document.createElement("td"));

    column.text(between[i]);

    line.append(column);

    table.append(line);
}
```

I separated the calls of methods to facilitate the intent of the code but it could be so:

```
for (var i in between) {
    var line = $(document.createElement("tr")),
        column = $(document.createElement("td"));

    table.append(line.append(column.text(between[i])));
}
```

Hope that helps!

[]'s